# stop mongodb creating dbs and collections dynamically

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to switch off the ability of mongo to sporadically create dbs and collections as soon as it sees one in a query. I run queries on the mongo console all the time and mistype a db or collection name, causing mongo to just create one. There should be a switch to have mongo only explicitly create dbs and collections. I can't find one on the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, implicit creation of collections and DBs is a feature of the console and may not be disabled. You might take a look at the [security/authorization/role](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-introduction/) features of 2.6 and see if anything might help (although there's not something that exactly matches your request as far as I know).

I'd suggest looking through the MongoDB issues/bug/requests database system [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) to and optionally add the feature request if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 10):

To be clear, MongoDB does not auto create collections or databases on queries. For collections, they are auto created when you actually save data to them. You can test this yourself, run a query on a previously unknown collection in a database like this:

```
use unknowndb
db.unknowncollection.find()
show collections
```

No collection named "unknowncollection" shows up until you insert or save into it.

Databases are a bit more complex. A simple `"use unknowndb"` will not auto create the database. However, if after you do that you run something like `"show collections"` it will create the empty database.

I agree, an option to control this behavior would be great. Happy to vote for it if you open a Jira ticket at mongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

For people who are using Mongoose, a new database will get created automatically if your Mongoose Schema contains any form of *index*. This is because Mongo needs to create a database before it can insert said index.